# simplexml_load_string is turning "&#160;" into "Â"

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm using [`simplexml_load_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) to load an XML document into an object. This seemed to be working great up until I came across this element:

```
<some_string_val>1.&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160; Some text.</some_string_val>
```

After running that ran through `simplexml_load_string`, what came out was:

```
["some_string_val"]=> string(20) "1.Â Â Â Â  Some text"
```

I tried using:

```
html_entity_decode($string,  ENT_QUOTES, "Windows-1252");
```

And that seemed to convert the `&#160;`'s to plain text, but when I tried to run that through `simplexml_load_string` I get the same result. I also tried with UTF-8, and a few others, with similar or worse results.

So, what can I do to convert the `&#160;`'s to UTF-8 so it can be parsed correctly by `simplexml_load_string`? Keeping the HTML entities intact is not a concern because this is going into a CSV.

EDIT: This has been unjustly marked as a duplicate for a couple of reasons:

1. This is not language agnostic; this is dealing with a specific set of PHP functions, unlike the post which this was marked a duplicate of
2. This is not going to an HTML page or a PDF, it is going to a CSV, so I cannot set a header. The accepted solution will not work in my case

Comment: `["some_string_val"]=> string(20) "1.Â Â Â Â  Some text"` is not output you see in your browser? I doubt that. I also verified it's a duplicate. For CSV files you might have to take a look in the manual of the software you open it with for *how to import a .csv file that uses UTF-8 character encoding*. The CSV file itself works very well with UTF-8 from PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it parses correctly. It just the way that function works, replacing those codes with special characters.

You can fix the result string, converting it into cp1251

```
$str = iconv('utf-8', 'cp1251', $str);
```

Also I would delete double spaces before writing it into CSV file

```
$str = str_replace(chr(160), ' ', $str);
$str= trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $str));
```

Comment: Would I need to do this before it feeds into `simplexml_load_string`? I tried after it had already gone through and didn't seem to do anything. I also did attempt to do it before, but I may have done it wrong.

Comment: @Samsquanch after, when you work with that XML object. Or better way would be to replace all special characters (&#160;) to it's equivalent before parsing XML. In that case you might not need to convert encoding and you'll save some time

Comment: just run this before parsing that string: $str = preg_replace('/&#160;/', ' ', $str);

Comment: Although I would have rather not done it this way, the `preg_replace` did end up working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXML itself has no problem to properly parse the XML:

```
$string = '<some_string_val>1.&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160; Some text.</some_string_val>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
echo $xml;
```

Output ([Demo](https://eval.in/204766)):

```
1.     Some text.
```

What happens is that after you have read out that UTF-8 string (`C2 A0`), you send it to somewhere and tell that somewhere not that it's UTF-8 encoded, but in a different encoding. Most likely Latin-1, I have to guess, you didn't share this kind of information with your question.

That somewhere will then display the binary sequence `C2 A0` as two characters:

1. `C2` Â
2. `A0` " " (No Break Space)

For example: You need to write into the CSV file. You can just write the data UTF-8 encoded there-in. When you open the CSV file in your spreadsheet application it should ask you about the encoding. Tell it to use Unicode UTF-8 Encoding. Then everything is fine.

If you display the array in your browser (this is how I read your question), then tell your browser that the website is in UTF-8. You should find an Encoding setting in your web-browsers menu to do that.